# Current time in ISO 8601 format

Tags: r, iso8601

For logging purposes, how can an R script get the current date and time, in the UTC time zone, as an ISO 8601 string in this format:

```
2015-12-31T14:26:56.600374+00:00
```

`as.POSIXlt` seems to be the solution, and the documentation claims that it accepts a format parameter, but I can't make that work (on R version 3.1.3):

```
> as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), "UTC", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-04-08 14:37:58 UTC"
> as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), tz="UTC", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-04-08 14:38:02 UTC"
> as.POSIXct(Sys.time(), tz="UTC", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-04-08 11:38:22 BRT"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`as.POSIXlt` (and `as.POSIXct`) are for input. Use either `format` or `strftime` for output. See ?strftime for details on format strings:

```
 tm <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), "UTC")
 strftime(tm , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
#[1] "2015-04-08T15:11:22+0000"
```

The third parameter of `as.POSIXlt`, `format`, is used when the first parameter is a string-like value that needs to be parsed. Since we are passing in a Date value from `Sys.time`, the `format` is ignored.

I don't think that the colon in the timezone output is requirement of the ISO 8601 format but I could be wrong on that point. The help page says the standard is POSIX 1003.1. May need to put in the colon with a regex substitution if needed.

After looking at http://dotat.at/tmp/ISO_8601-2004_E.pdf I see that there is no colon in the "basic" format" timezone representation, but there is one in the "extended format".

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Still, the "format" (3rd) parameter of `as.POSIXlt` doesn't seem to make a difference. Changing it, even removing the time part, didn't change the output. This seems to work: `strftime(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), "UTC"), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")`.

Comment: Right. You code is what I did except you omitted the intermediate variable creation. When you use unnamed argument positional matching is used so when we gave it a numeric value, it matched that format to the "..." parameter of the `as.POSIXlt.POSIXct` function. And then it basically ignored it, anyway. It doesn't get passed to the internal function.

Comment: I think what OP is confused about here is the fact that `as.POSIXlt(x=Sys.time(), tz="UTC", format="%Y-%m-%d")` and `as.POSIXlt(x=Sys.time(), tz="UTC")` return exactly the same thing. This is a confusing result of polymorphism with the `x` parameter. The `format` parameter is completely ignored unless `x` is string-like.

Comment: @7yl4r Thanks. You are quite right that my earlier code had a superfluous parameter in the context of a "Date"-classed value.

Comment: The format `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"` appears to fall between the `basic` and `extended` ISO formats.  The date and time parts have punctuation, but the time zone offset does not.  This is rejected by SQL Server as a valid date/time for `datetimeoffset` data type. the suggestion about adding the colon into the offset with a regex substitution seems to be necessary in this case.  I would appreciate an example of an effective way to do this.

Comment: This appears to work where x is in the format above:  `sub('(+[0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}$)','\\1:\\2', x , fixed=FALSE)`

Comment: For file names, `"%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"` seems fair enough to me, maybe `paste0` a `"Z"` if UTC/GMT was used. _Example:_ `"20230326T183011Z"`.

Answer (score 8):

The package `parsedate` recognizes and parses Dates in various formats, including all ISO 8601 Formats:

```
format_iso_8601(Sys.time())
# [1] "2017-09-01T10:59:22+00:00"
```