# R: To convert POSIXct format to Javascript JSON Date format

Tags: r, json, datetime

My date time format is:

```
 POSIXct, format: "2018-11-05 12:09:12"
```

I want to send this data to Power BI for creating reports. But Power BI has the following data format:

```
"2018-11-05T12:59:06.856Z" -  which is a 'JavaScript built-in JSON object'
```

How do I convert my POSIXct date to the above JSON format? I have seen examples for converting date time to POSIXct and few other formatting rules, but not JSON.

Comment: So, is a 'JavaScript built-in JSON object' just a character string or something else internally? If the latter, what is it and can you (i) pass it from R or (ii) need to pass a character string and parse it in JavaScript?

Comment: @Roland It's some internal format (Power BI just had an example), from the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format, found that it was Javascript JSON format.

Comment: AFAIK JSON is simply text. So, you probably simply need to study `help("strptime")`.

Comment: This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517896/current-time-in-iso-8601-format