# Convert date-time to string in R

Tags: r, datetime

An argument for an API requires me to format time as YYYYMMDDHHMM, i.e. 3 March 2019 14:30 would be "201903031430". I'm trying to do some operations beforehand and then convert the result into that string format, but I haven't come up with anything succinct. For example, using `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

paste0(year(now()),month(now()),day(now()),hour(now()),minute(now()))

> [1] "2020122105"
```

Not only looks horrible, but also does not pad zeroes for days and hours as required. I can tweak the relevant ones further for zero-padding, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of reversing the typical string-to-datetime conversion.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with `format` `format(now(), "%Y%m%d%H%M")`

Comment: Base R:  `strftime(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d%H%M")`

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a much easier way... I need to consider/look into base R a bit more. If either of you would like to put this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of  [Current time in ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517896/current-time-in-iso-8601-format) or [Extracting time from POSIXct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839343/extracting-time-from-posixct/9839566#9839566)

Comment: @wibeasley, I think the problem is that those are a lot more specific and did not show up when I did a DDG search or when writing my question (which I did pretty much expecting something to have already been asked). Happy for this to be closed, but I thought I'd mention that.

Comment: @FonsMA, sorry they didn't show up.  If you're happy that these posts are similar enough to someone searching for this, it's probably best if you close it as a duplicate.